# ffmpeg -vcopy to folder without filename

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to find a command line to copy part of videos and export them to a different folder.

The problem i need to solve is each file may have different extensions, .mxf, .dv, .avi etc some came from a internal url server that gives download links like /server/download?id=1000 and that will download an mp4, or a mxf so i have no idea the extension.. the name is not important..

i want to know if it's possible or there's an existing command line where the -y file.extension is not needed.

For example

ffmpeg.exe -i "/server/download?id=1000" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -y "folder/"

An i get a filename.avi or filename.mxf inside that "folder/"

Comment: Those urls redirect to ones with an appropriate extension?  So your question is how to name the output file the right container extension? Or do you care about container type?

Comment: I have 2 ways to do this.. one, download the file, get the file extension and then run ffmpeg.. that's not a problem.. but will take some extra time because i need to download the video first ..

Option 2 is :

Run ffmpeg and take the video directly from the webserver but the problem is i don't know what format the file is.. have sence??

Comment: So it redirects to ones with an appropriate extension?  What is your end goal with using ffmpeg why not just download the video, are you moving them into a new container type?

Comment: i'm usign ffmpeg to extract 10 seconds for example from a 2 hours video.. it save tons of gigs of bandwith and time..  imagine to copy a 20gigs video and then extract 10 seconds.. i extract it directly from the original online file.

This works perfect for my needs.. 

ffmpeg.exe -i "/server/download?id=1000" -t 00:00:10 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -y "folder/video.mxf"

As you can see i set the name video.mxf... but the problem is if the file 1001 is a mp4 so i have to check first the file extension..

Comment: So seems there's no such feature... but your suggestion is a good solution.. Thanks you very much Roger! sorry for my english! is hard to explain in another language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.mxf` is a container format, so just pulling it in like `ffmpeg -i http://xx -vcodec copy -acodec copy OUTPUT.mp4` might work regardless of the input (if it starts as an `.mxf` then ffmpeg will basically re-container it into an `mp4` container).  (it will "re-container" the same elemental video/audio streams, which will remain unmodified, I assume that was your initial intent). If you really want to keep the containers also the same, you might be able to run `ffmpeg -i http:///xx` first, which might tell you the container type, then turn around and run it like `ffmpeg -i http://xx  -vcodec copy -acodec copy output.ext`

Comment: *if it starts as an .mxf then ffmpeg will basically re-container it into an mp4 container* --> I'm not clear what this means. Can you elaborate?

Comment: There are two things at play, the video and audio streams are contained within a "container" format which keeps track of timestamps of each frame, etc.  There are different container formats.  `mp4` is a container format, as is `mxf` FWIW

Comment: I understand that. But "`ffmpeg -i http://xx.mp4` *might work regardless of the input*" won't work if the resolved input serves no resource at that modified address, Also, adding a suffix to the input won't force a specific demuxer. ffmpeg relies on a probe function.

Comment: oops something of a typo, I've attempted to clarify :)

Comment: Ok but now you're transcoding. OP wants to `copy`. `mkv` or `nut` will be safer choices to avoid codec support failures.